# problem with feeding input files into gdal_merge.py

Tags: gdal, gdal-merge

While merging the files using gdal_merge.py the following code works:

```
subprocess.call([sys.executable,gmerge,'-o','C:\\r.tif','-of','GTiff','D:\\a.tif','D:\\b.tif'],shell=True)
```

However, when the input files are numerous, each file can not be inserted separately. In this case, the following code does not work:

```
subprocess.call([sys.executable,gmerge,'-o','C:\\r.tif','-of','GTiff','D:\\*.tif'],shell=True)
```

I did not know how to input the input files.
Any idea is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can loop on your files and append them to your list

```
command = [sys.executable,gmerge,'-o','C:\\r.tif','-of','GTiff']

images = glob.glob("D:\\*.tif")
for image in images:
    command.append(image)

subprocess.call(command)
```

Comment: No need to loop. This will work as well `subprocess.call(command+images)`